# Aplicar between em uma hql no c#

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

Estou tentando aplica um between com dois campos de uma parte do meu formulário, são datas e ids de veículos, não tenho muito conhecimento de como modela isso pela HQL no nhibernate com c#, queria saber como seria para aplica isso na hql.

Normalmente as minhas consultas usando HQL são assim:

```
public IList<Abastecimento> ConsultaData(DateTime DtAbastecido)
    {
        string hql = "SELECT a FROM Abastecimento a";
        IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
        return query.List<Abastecimento>();
    }
```

Utilizando consulta como essa eu depois uso no controller aplico do seguinte modo:

```
var Rota = ckm.ConsultaProduto(viewModel.NumCarroId);
```

Eu queria sabe como faria para colocar um between trazendo datas, um exemplo seria que me trouxesse um registro de 01/11/2017 até 01/12/2017, queria saber como é que seria a consulta HQL aplicando o between com duas textbox que irei usa no form.

Comment: qual é o nome da coluna da Data?

Comment: recomendo a leitura
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Comment: @LeandroAngelo O nome da coluna é DtAbastecido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue um exemplo

```
public IList<Abastecimento> ConsultaPeriodo(DateTime dataInicio, DateTime dataFim)
{
    string hql = "SELECT a FROM Abastecimento a WHERE a.DtAbastecimento BETWEEN :dataInicial AND :dataFinal";
    IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql)
        .SetParameter("dataInicial", dataInicio)
        .SetParameter("dataFinal", dataFinal);
    return query.List<Abastecimento>();
}
```

Comment: Na parte de setParameter, ele ira pega a minha ViewBag que contem o meus valores? É isso que o setParameter faz então?

Comment: Ele irá pegar os valores que você passar como parâmetro no método ConsultaPeriodo

Comment: Como a sua pergunta era relativa à hql, essa seria a abordagem.

Comment: É que essa linha setParameter, eu vi em uns exemplos usando login e senha de usuario, mas não sabia como era utilizado, agora acho que entendi como funciona

Comment: Acho que as vezes você está confundindo o que é banco, entidade e quando está interagindo com cada um.

Comment: Na verdade estou começando recentemente com c#, estou meio confuso com ele, e ainda tem as framework que está dificultando o meu entedimento entre a interação do banco com as entidades

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70513/discussion-between-leandro-angelo-and-guilherme-padovam).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a expressão "Where" e utilizar os atributos IsBetween para pegar um resultado dentro de uma data estimada.

```
Where(r => r.data.IsBetween(dataInicio).And(dataFim)).List();
```